# When I detach an object that has a relation to another cached entity, is that detached as well?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I was wondering what happens when I detach an object that has a relation to another cached entity, is that detached as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The relation is set to null (or collection navigation property is cleared). There is no way to detach object graph. The best workaround is to make a deep copy of attached entities by using serialization and deserialization.

Answer (score 2):

No, the navigation properties are set to null.

You can take use of [.AsNoTracking()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to query a detached subtree.